# how to pass multiple attributes to the option in Thymelaef

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to using thymeleaf as the view template and i come across one problem. the code I have now is as below.

`<select>
    <option th:each="res: ${result1}"
        th:value="${result1.NAME}"
        th:text="${result1.NAME}"></option>
    </select>`

What I need is like this, where I dont know how to add another attribute for **result2**, both **result1** and **result2** are the list object in the controller

`<select>
    <option th:each="res: ${result1}"
        th:value="${res.NAME}"
        th:text="${res.NAME+result2.SCHOOL}"></option>
    </select>`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple object with two fields for result1 and result2, if you know their relationship in the controller. Then you can use a list of that objects to iterate in html page.

```
<select>
<option th:each="item: ${itemList}"
    th:value="${item.result1.NAME}"
    th:text="${item.result1.NAME + item.result2.SCHOOL}"></option>
</select>
```